# RDLC expression to display specific records only

Tags: c#, sql-server, rdlc

i have the result from stored procedure and show it on RDLC.
the result like this:

```
Code    Name        
----    ------------
11      Boeing
12      LockHead
21      Airbus
22      Bombardier
31      Antonov
```

and i want to display it on 3 tablix like this

```
Tablix 1
Code    Name        
----    ------------
11      Boeing
12      LockHead


Tablix 2
Code    Name        
----    ------------
21      Airbus
22      Bombardier


Tablix 3
Code    Name        
----    ------------
31      Antonov
```

Please help me with the expresion.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to group your data using an `Expression`.

Looking at your example it seems that this expressions could work:

```
=Floor(Fields!Code.Value/10)
```